# VBA for Visio 2013 to save as SVG

Tags: vba, svg, visio

I need a macro which will allow me to save the current Visio drawing as an SVG file.

The quickest way I can do at the moment is to use the <kbd>F12</kbd> keyboard shortcut which gives me the Save As dialog, but still each time I have to select the proper output file, i.e. PNG, and then write the name of the file.

Is it possible to automate this? I was looking for something like Macro recording in Visio, but couldn't find that.

Comment: To record a macro, turn on developer mode (this will show you "advanced" functions like macro revcording which are hidden by default). Try googling "developr mode visio".

Comment: I saw that, but how I make the macro available all over the Visio?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no straightforward solution to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file formats of .bmp, .dib, .dwg, .dxf, .emf, .emz, .gif, .htm, .jpg, .png, .svg, .svgz, .tif, or .wmf

The extension will define the format.

```
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page 
Set vsoPage = ActivePage 
vsoPage.Export ("C:\\myExportedPage.svg")
```

Here is an example of looping all pages exporting each one.

```
Dim PgObj    As Visio.Page 
Dim Pgs      As Visio.Pages 
Dim filename As String 
Dim PgName   As String 
Dim iPgs     As Integer 

'Set a handle to the pages collection
Set Pgs = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages 

'Loop Pages collections
For iPgs = 1 To Pgs.Count 
    'Set a handle to a page
    Set PgObj = Pgs(iPgs) 

    'Get Page name
    PgName = PgObj.Name 
    'Create path to save svg file
    filename = Application.ActiveDocument.Path & PgName & ".svg" 
    'Export the page as svg file
    PgObj.Export filename 
Next iPgs 

'Clean Up
Set PgObj = Nothing 
Set Pgs = Nothing
```

Comment: Made a change. The above will give you SVG.