# Visio VSTO AddIn "save as" SVG

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I have a basic question about developing Visio VSTO AddIn using VS 2019. Is it possible to programmatically save a Visio Page in any other format than *.vsd or *.vsdx? The Visio UI allows "save as" a scalable vector graphic (SVG). However, looking at the Visio object model reference I cannot see any way to save in a format other than *.vsd / *.vsdx? Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Here's a massive programming tip, the MS Object Model is the same for VBA as it is with C# (applies to almost any object model), there's some slight syntax differences but it's easy to convert. Give this a go with this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791331/495455

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Export" instead of "Save": 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.export

You could also try my extension for extended SVG export :D

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking a look at Nikolay's SVG Publish extension for Visio, this SVG export add-in provides you with many more useful export options that Visio itself does not offer.

https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/

Comment: It is not a direct answer, but the experience is that the SVG export of Visio is limited and more expanded functionality is needed for a lot of use cases, I think it may be a necessary part of the answer for this user.

Comment: Thanks @DotNETFan we have developed our own Visio publishing plugin that generates rich HTML web content based upon the underlying SVG: https://crecy.com.au/model-gen/

Comment: Andrew I checked it out very impressive tool, I did not even know it existed!